# Connecting to mySQL using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL Database using the mysql-connector-jar, which gets imported via maven. I have the dependency in the POM file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

And I initialize my connection with the code below:

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:host";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "update aem_assets set path = (?), assetid = (?), filename = (?), cadid = (?) where id = (?)";
try {
    Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
```

However, I keep getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found`. I am trying to avoid manually adding the jar to the build path since my company uses maven for builds and we want this tool to be run from multiple instances without having to add jars.

I have also tried it without the `newInstance()` method.

I am referencing this article for implementation: https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/jdbc-mysql-maven-working-example/

Edit: I have added the JAR file to the module dependency.  [image]

However it is STILL giving me the error. Am I missing something?

Comment: check this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779631/jdbc-driver-class-not-found-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: You need the JAR on the runtime classpath, not at build time

Comment: Did you notice the note on the blog page that says "During runtime the MySQL driver is loaded into classpath using the reflective *Class.forName();* By the way, since JDBC 4.0, this is not necessary and this line can be omitted."

Comment: How are you executing this. The driver is not on the runtime classpath. Also except with a very old (10+ years ago), buggy MySQL driver, using `newInstance()` has never been necessary.

Comment: I repeat my question: How are you executing this?

Comment: A servlet calls it. I am deploying the code to a localhost server where a front end javascript calls the backend servlet, which executes the method with the database initialization.